# JavaScript - object(s) referring to itself

Tags: javascript

I'm in a middle of doing some helpers library and I found an interesting problem. Namely, how can I - from within a function - refer to an object that has ran the said function?

Perhaps my explanation isn't clear, so here's the code:

HTML

```
<div class=".ful">...</div>
```

JS

```
class Moon {
    onEvents(what, events, callback) {
        const ev = events.split(' ');

        for (let t of Array.from(what)) {
            for (let e of ev) {
                t.addEventListener(e, () => {
                    callback();
                });
            }
        }
    }
}

const moon = new Moon();

moon.onEvents(document.querySelectorAll('.ful'), 'click mouseover', () => { console.log('identikit'); });
```

This works great, but when I want something like

```
moon.onEvents(document.querySelectorAll('.ful'), 'click mouseover', () => { console.log(this); });
```

I am getting `undefined`. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of an arrow function is to bind the *current* value of `this`. If you don't want to do that, don't use an arrow function.

```
moon.onEvents(document.querySelectorAll('.ful'), 'click mouseover', function () { console.log(this); });
```

and

```
t.addEventListener(e, callback);
```